# function with disconnected dense graph

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Assume we have a function $f$ with dense graph, that is, $$\{\langle x, f(x)\rangle\colon x\in\mathbb R\}\cap (U\times V)\neq\emptyset$$ for every open set $U,V\subset\mathbb R.$ let $\ell_a(x)=ax$ where $a\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}.$ Let $I$ be an open interval,if $$f(x)\neq\ell_a(x)$$ for every  $x\in I,$ then $f$ has a disconnected graph. I think it is correct since $f$ has a dense graph so it will have points from both side of the line. So, we can have  separates that make the graph disconnected. Is it true ? Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, disconnected

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I edited. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work a little harder than that. There must be $u,v\in I$ such that $u<v$, and $\langle u,f(u)\rangle$ and $\langle v,f(v)\rangle$ are on the same side of $\ell_a$. Without loss of generality assume that $f(u)>au$ and $f(v)>av$. Let

$$U=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:u<x<v\text{ and }y<ax\right\}\,,$$

the set of points between the lines $x=u$ and $x=v$ and below $\ell_a$. Let $G$ be the graph of $f$. Then $U\cap G\ne\varnothing\ne G\setminus U$, and $U\cap G$ is a relatively open subset of $G$, so it only remains to show that $G\setminus U$ is relatively open in $G$.

We can do this by showing that $U\cap G$ is relatively closed in $G$ which is easy: we’ve carefully chosen $U$ so that

$$\operatorname{cl}U=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:u\le x\le v\text{ and }y\le ax\right\}=U\,,$$

and $U\cap G$ is therefore clopen in $G$.

Comment: Brian M.Scott. I just  envision it geometrically by having  two points from different sides of the line and this can happen since my graph is dense otherwise it is not necessary to be true . So, I can find separator . Hence, the graph is disconnected. Is my think wrong?

Comment: @00GB: You’re guaranteed to have points on both sides of the line, but that’s not enough by itself to prove that the graph is disconnected: you still have to show that the graph is the union of two disjoint, relatively open subsets, that what happens outside $I$ doesn’t somehow make the graph connected. Your basic idea is good, but the details take a bit of work.

Comment: Brain M. Scott, I think in your definition of $U$ you meant, $y<ax$ right ?

Comment: @00GB: I did indeed; thanks for catching that.